# ¿Como eliminar archivos temporarales de actualizaciones fallidas en open suse?

Tags: linux, opensuse

Tengo el Open Suse 42.3 y tuvo una actualización fallida, quisiera 
saber algún comando para eliminar archivos temporales, y así  liberar espacio en particular de la partición / que se  esta quedando 
llena.

De antemano gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Desde Yast no hay opciones para borrar temporales?

Comment: Investigando encontre este comando sed 's/^d/D/' /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf > /etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf que se sugiere en este post  https://elpinguinotolkiano.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/limpieza-de-archivos-temporales-en-opensuse/

Comment: Si funciona ponlo como respuesta ;)